# Sahara service failed to start during devstack installation

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-juno

I am installing devstack Juno and at the end it ended up with an error stating that

> sahara failed to start

Here are the details about this error, I am not able to figure it out, kindly help me with this.

```
/usr/local/bin/sahara-all --config-file /etc/sahara/sahara.conf
2015-02-15 20:53:21.426 INFO sahara.main [-] Starting Sahara all-in-one
2015-02-15 20:53:21.426 INFO sahara.utils.rpc [-] Notifications enabled
2015-02-15 20:53:22.676 INFO sahara.plugins.base [-] Plugin 'hdp' loaded sahara.plugins.hdp.ambariplugin:AmbariPlugin
2015-02-15 20:53:22.677 INFO sahara.plugins.base [-] Plugin 'vanilla' loaded sahara.plugins.vanilla.plugin:VanillaProvider
2015-02-15 20:53:22.677 INFO sahara.plugins.base [-] Plugin 'fake' loaded sahara.plugins.fake.plugin:FakePluginProvider
2015-02-15 20:53:22.725 DEBUG sahara.main [-] Logging of request/response exchange could be enabled using flag --log-exchange from (pid=847) make_app /opt/stack/sahara/sahara/main.py:144
2015-02-15 20:53:22.726 INFO keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Starting keystone auth_token middleware
2015-02-15 20:53:22.727 INFO keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] Using /var/cache/sahara as cache directory for signing certificate
2015-02-15 20:53:22.819 WARNING keystonemiddleware.auth_token [-] signing_dir mode is 0755 instead of 0700
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 CRITICAL sahara [-] TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: str

2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara   File "/usr/local/bin/sahara-all", line 9, in <module>
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara     load_entry_point('sahara==2014.2.3.dev1', 'console_scripts', 'sahara-all')()
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara   File "/opt/stack/sahara/sahara/cli/sahara_all.py", line 56, in main
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara     app = server.make_app()
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara   File "/opt/stack/sahara/sahara/main.py", line 151, in make_app
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara     app.wsgi_app = acl.wrap(app.wsgi_app, CONF)
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara   File "/opt/stack/sahara/sahara/api/acl.py", line 31, in wrap
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara     return auth_token.AuthProtocol(app, conf=auth_cfg)
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token.py", line 661, in __init__
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara     seconds=self._conf_get('revocation_cache_time'))
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: str
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara 
sahara failed to start
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ceilometer/+bug/1383751). The problem is the `revocation_cache_time` setting needs to be set or else it treats it as a string. Simply uncomment the setting in the `/etc/ceilometer/ceilometer.conf` and restart the service.

Comment: thanks for your answer, no it does not work, and there is nothing to uncomment, I think issue is in the file 
`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystonemiddleware/auth_token.py", line 661, in __init__
2015-02-15 20:53:22.820 TRACE sahara     seconds=self._conf_get('revocation_cache_time'))`

I am not sure what should i replace revocation_cache_time with? Any words please?